# What happens if a multi module project is built with force update snapshots?

Tags: maven, multi-module

Assume I have a parent project which has three modules, module1 module2 and module3. There are some dependency between these modules, e.g:

module1 --depends on--> module2

module3 --depends on--> module2

Now if I run "mvn -U install" to force update the snapshots, when the reactor gets to building module1, does it build it against my local version of module2 or the latest from the remote repository?

Comment: Which Version of Maven do you use? Have you correctly defined the dependencies between your modules? If so you don't need to give the `-U` cause the dependencies between those modules are resolved through the reactor so it will get something from outside the reactor?

Comment: @khmarbaise One note I should add is that I don't have a problem. I'm just wondering what will happen if I use `-U`. I'm using Maven 3.1.1.

Comment: The `-U` is only intended to update SNAPSHOT's which are located outside the reactor.